# Asp mvc como alterar dados da model e passar para outra view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou iniciando em asp net mvc e não estou conseguindo pegar os dados alterados de um model simples e passar para uma outra view. Segue os códigos:

Model:

```
public class Produto
    {
        public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Tamanho { get; set; }
        public double Valor { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller método index que mostra dados da model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {

            Produto produto = new Models.Produto
            {
                ProdutoId = 1,
                Descricao = "Calça jeans Pitbull",
                Tipo = "Calça",
                Tamanho = "40",
                Valor = 59.99



            };

            ViewData["ProdutoId"] = produto.ProdutoId;
            ViewData["Descricao"] = produto.Descricao;
            ViewData["Tipo"] = produto.Tipo;
            ViewData["Tamanho"] = produto.Tamanho;
            ViewData["Valor"] = produto.Valor;


            return View();
        }

    @model Introducao.Models.Produto
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}
```

Método Lista que irá alterar os dados da model:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Lista(int? ProdutoId, string Descricao, string Tipo, string Tamanho, double? Valor)
        {
            Produto produto = new Models.Produto();
            TempData["Produto"] = produto;

            ViewData["ProdutoId"] = ProdutoId;
            ViewData["Descricao"] = Descricao;
            ViewData["Tipo"] = Tipo;
            ViewData["Tamanho"] = Tamanho;
            ViewData["Valor"] = Valor;


            return View(produto);
        }
```

View Lista que irá mostrar os dados alterados da model:

```
<h2>Meu Site!</h2>
<p>Meu Conteúdo</p>
<form action="Home/Lista" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Produtos</legend>

        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoId">Código</label>
        </div>
        <input type="number" value="@ViewData["ProdutoId"]" name="TxtProdutoId" />
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoDescricao">Descrição</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Descricao"]" name="TxtProdutoDescricao" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoTipo">Tipo</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Tipo"]" name="TxtProdutoTipo" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoTamanho">Tamanho</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Tamanho"]" name="TxtProdutoTamanho" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoValor">Valor(Unit.)</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Valor"]" name="TxtProdutoValor" />
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Aí neste caso quando eu executo o projeto e passo os valores do meu txt na index e mando ele passar para a view lista executando esta alteração ele informa que o método vem nulo.
Pode ser uma questão bem besta neh kkk mas estou aqui buscando conhecimento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Produto produto = new Models.Produto
        {
            ProdutoId = 1,
            Descricao = "Calça jeans Pitbull",
            Tipo = "Calça",
            Tamanho = "40",
            Valor = 59.99
        };

        return View(produto);
    }
```

Assim você recuperaria os valores na View().

```
@model Models.Produto
<form action="Home/Lista" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Produtos</legend>

    <div>
        <label for="LblProdutoId">Código</label>
    </div>
    <input type="number" value="@Model.ProdutoId" name="ProdutoId" />
    <div>
        <label for="Descricao">Descrição</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Descricao" name="Descricao" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Tipo">Tipo</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Tipo" name="Tipo" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="tamanho">Tamanho</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Tamanho" name="Tamanho" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Valor">Valor(Unit.)</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" value="@Model.Valor" name="Valor" />
    </div>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
</fieldset>
```

Se os valores já estiverem chegando por parâmetro no seu método **Lista()** acredito que poderia melhora-lo fazendo assim:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Lista(Models.Produto produto)
    {
        //Instancia seu objeto
        Produto produto = produto;

        return View(produto);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa das ViewData, pois quando você manda o seu modelo para a view, que nesse caso é um objeto do tipo produto, ele já recupera todas as informações que você precisa.
O que você precisa é apenas inserir, la na primeira linha da sua view, o código:

```
@model nomeProjeto.seuModelo
```

e onde na sua View tem @ViewData, você substitui por:

```
@Model.campoProduto
```

Por exemplo:

```
@Model.Tamanho
```

Isso deve resolver.
 você inserindo essa tag que eu mensionei acima, ele já recupera todas as informações que você inseriu no seu controler.

Answer (score 2):

O Asp.Net MVC consegue passar os dados para *Actions* via parâmetros de **tipo primitivo** (int, string, double, etc...) ou de **tipo complexo** (um objeto, como Models.Produto por exemplo).

No seu exemplo, usando **tipos primitivos**, quando você faz o *POST* da página, o MVC tentará associar os dados do formulário aos parâmetros de *Action* por nome.

O nome dos campos do seu formulário precisam ser os mesmos nomes dos campos que sua *Action* Lista espera.

Então uma forma de resolver é renomear os campos do formulário conforme os campos da *Action*.

Altere sua View **Index**:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Produto

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<h2>Meu Site!</h2>
<p>Meu Conteúdo</p>
<form action="Lista" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Produtos</legend>

        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoId">Código</label>
        </div>
        <input type="number" value="@ViewData["ProdutoId"]" name="ProdutoId" />
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoDescricao">Descrição</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Descricao"]" name="Descricao" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoTipo">Tipo</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Tipo"]" name="Tipo" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoTamanho">Tamanho</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Tamanho"]" name="Tamanho" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="LblProdutoValor">Valor(Unit.)</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@ViewData["Valor"]" name="Valor" />
        </div>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Renomeiei o atributo `name` dos *inputs* de:

TxtProdutoId,
TxtProdutoDescricao,
TxtProdutoTipo,
TxtProdutoTamanho,
TxtProdutoValor

Para:

ProdutoId,
Descricao,
Tipo,
Tamanho,
Valor

Assim, quando você clicar em Enviar, o MVC vai fazer um *POST* na *Action* Lista (conforme a linha `<form action="Lista" method="post">`), verificando o nome dos campos do formulário com os respectivos nomes dos campos que a Action Lista espera.

Comment: Galera. Resolveram, fiz todas as modificações que informaram , me ajudou a limpar minha aplicação cheia de códigos inúteis. Valeu mesmo, a todos meus sinceros agradecimento!!:)